# Trim / Casing and Baseboard choices between rooms

Tags: finishing, router, design, trim

I understand this is partially design, however I think it's part of the art of fine trim carpenters.  This is my second floor sitting room which has routed 1x8s as baseboard and 1x6 with the same round over bit as the window casings.  Attached is a photo

[image: sitting room]

Inside my master bedroom, lower ceilings the previous owner used 1x6 baseboards and 1x4 casings with a smaller profile roman ogee bit.

[image: roman ogee window]

This leads me to my question having the deep round over bit being used in my main room and transitioning to using a roman ogee bit in the bedrooms with 1x4 is this an ok transition to make.  I have another bedroom on the same floor when I purchased had no trim. As seen here. [image: bedroom without trim]

If you were making new trim for your bedrooms would you worry about matching the main adjoining room?  And If matching is not critical is a roman ogee profile in a room next to a really wide round over acceptable.

Adding one photo for the view between rooms. The first window seen is the 1x4 roman and the other windows are the round over style.  As you may see using a larger 1x6 casing around the door maybe interesting

[image]

My mockup of casing baseboard and backband

[image]

Thanks for all of your help

Comment: Ultimately I decided on making custom casing with a classical ogee bit with a filet.   I bought the lumber, routed it and primed. I'll begin installing tomorrow and I'll follow up with my findings